# Easier way to compare variables

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, for-loop, comparison

I need to compare a set of variables from file 'tmpcsv2' with variables in 'uniq_id', I'm detailing the files below.

tmpcsv2 -> This file gets updated by another script 'script1' and each run of 'script1' updates (not append) new variables in 'tmpcsv2'. The no. of variables might be 1 and can go till 200.

```
eg:
2042344352
2470697747
2635527510
3667769962
```

uniq-id -> This is a fixed set of variables (about 100K in no.)

```
(Business Name,Job ID,Job Size)
biz,1000036446,225210640
biz,100006309,6710840
biz,1000069211,2084019000
biz,1000118720,34194040
biz,1000150241,212322636
```

I'm using 'for' loops + 'if' to compare them as shown below, is there a easier or faster (less impact) way of doing this ? When I run this it take a very long time to output results. The print commands are just for testing and will be removed later!

```
****Part of a bigger script****
amt=0
mjc=0
for jbid in `cat tmpcsv2` #Pick ID for match & calculation
do
    printf "Checking ID $jbid\n" >> Acsv3.tmp
    for bsid in `cat uniq_id` #Matching jobs & size calulation
    do
        ckid=`echo $bsid | cut -d "," -f2` #ckid is the ID to check
        jbsiz=`echo $bsid | cut -d "," -f3` #size of the ID
        if [ $jbid == $ckid ] 
        then
            printf "Matched at $ckid\n" #Print on Match found
            printf "Valid -> $jbid\n" >> Bcsv3.tmp
            ((mjc++)) #Increment Matched Job Count
            amt=$((amt+jbsiz)) #Add size of matched jobs
            break
        else
            printf "No Match at $cksid\n" #No matches
        fi
    done
    printf "Check for ID $jbid done\n" >> Acsv3.tmp
    printf "Matched $mjc jobs with combined size of $amt\n" >> Acsv3.tmp
done
****End of Comparision****
```

Comment: What is the exact format of your input? Note you aren't actually using the `jbid` variable anywhere except for output, so the comparisons themselves don't even involve that file.

Comment: @ormaaj, I have edited the script to show the use of 'jbid' , I use it to compare the variables.

Answer (score 1):

A shell is the wrong tool for crunching this much data, but it's doable. The most basic mistake here is [reading lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Performance may be improved significantly by not re-opening the files on each iteration.

```
function main {
    # Variables used elsewhere should be initialized there, not localized here.
    typeset amt=0 mjc=0 jbid ckid jbsiz

    while IFS= read -r jbid; do
        printf 'Checking ID %s\n' "$jbid" >&3
        while IFS=, read -r _ ckid jbsiz _; do
            case $jbsiz in
                *[^[:digit:]]*|'')
                    # validation is important for subsequent arithmetic.
                    return 1
                    ;;
                "$ckid") # Assuming "cksid" was a typo. Replace if not.
                    printf 'Matched at %s\n' "$ckid"
                    printf 'Valid -> %s\n' "$jbid" >&4
                    (( mjc++, amt += jbsiz ))
                    break
                    ;;
                *)
                    printf 'No match at %s\n' "$ckid"
            esac
        done <uniqid
        {
            printf 'Check for ID %s done\n' "$jbid"
            printf 'Matched %s jobs with combined size of %s\n' "$mjc" "$amt"
        } >&3
    done <tmpcsv2 3>>Acsv3.tmp 4>>Bcsv3.tmp
}
```

Finally, an equivalent awk script will significantly outperform this Bash script, as will nearly any other language. You can also get a lot more performance out of Bash by using `mapfile` instead of a read loop, but this nested read loop logic is a bit sloppy to emulate using `mapfile` callbacks.

Comment: Is this shell ? and can u frame a awk with similar logic ?

Comment: This is shell, using a bit of bash/ksh-specific syntax. Hopefully it's close to what you want. I could do awk, but somebody else can probably do a better job than me... I usually have to RTFM a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this, not sure if this can be shortened, but it sure runs faster ! Any help will be much appreciated !

```
************
while read -r line  #File read start
do
IFS=$","
val=$line
amt=0
mjc=0
cjc=0
for lsid in $val
do
    cksid=`echo $lsid | sed -e 's/*//g' -e 's/"//g'`
    printf "Checking for $cksid\n"
    ((cjc++)) #Count of jobs to check
    prsnt=`grep -w $cksid uniq_id`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        printf "Valid -> $cksid\n"
        jbsiz=`grep -w $prsnt | cut -d, -f2`
        (( mjc++, amt += jbsiz ))
        break
    else
        printf "No Data for $cksid\n"
    fi

done
done < tmpcsv2
***********
```

Comment: I almost had a taste of victory with this script.... but, I used 'grep' and that is not causing me grief! grep is making all three values look same! -->  448742, 3660'448742', 115'448742'464

Comment: I've made some changes to my input file and now grep works fine! Can anyone please check and let me know whether this is a good method for comparison ?